# How do I update all documents in mongodb PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am setting up a cronjob to update the field `views_15` on all documents from collection `query`.

This is what I had, that should have worked:

```
    $update = array(
        '$set' => array (
            'views_15' => 0
            )
    );

    $db->queries->update(array(), $update, array('multi' => true));
```

Also it works for a specific query!

So what should I use instead of `array()`, from the < query > parameter to select all documents?

Comment: can someone enlighten me why this post was voted down?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace `'multi'` with `'multiple'` in the options to your update command:

```
$db->queries->update(array(), $update, array('multiple' => true));
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php for all the valid update options.