# Will mongo cursor affected while update on the same collection?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have some code like following,

```
$query = array("vid"=>"just_a_video_key_and_can_be_any_string");
$set = array("$set" => array("attr" => "attr_value"));
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor = $cursor->batchSize(500);
foreach ($cursor as $item) {
    $collection->update($query, $set)
}
```

I find the loop times is 500, while the $collection has 20K+ documents.

The update operation only update one document, not involving delete or insert.

**My question is** why the `foreach` loop only 500 times(which is the number of batch size) while the total documents in the database is more than 20K?

Comment: The code seems to be incomplete. What is $query and what is $set?
Without these variables it is impossible to give you an answer as we just don't know WHAT kind of update you're doing (is $item anywhere in the query)?

Comment: @Osterjour sorry for incomplete code. I have completed it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're confused about why mongodb is only updating one document.

Mongodb only updates one document at a time. To update *all* documents which match your query, pass the `multiple` option to mongodb via `'multiple' => true`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691466/2416049

Comment: sorry for incomplete code. I have completed it. See the newly edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach only iterates 500 times because your batch size is 500. You need to call next() or getnext() to retrieve the next 500 elements.

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.batchsize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.next.php

Comment: I don' think so. At first, I use `while ($item = $cursor->getNext())` to loop over the cursor. The result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You try to update inside the foreach loop with a query which hasn't anything from $item in it. So your query will always run against the same document (vid: "just_a_video_key_and_can_be_any_string") and not against the items... you need to set query inside of the foreach to something like `"vid" => $item->vid`.
Regarding the "only 500" thing: LinJuuichi is right - you need to trigger the cursor via next() to get the next batch of 500.

Comment: `MongoCursor::getNext() is an alias of MongoCursor::next().` And `foreach` is the same as getNext. So the point is why the loop times is 500, in other words, when the cursor try to get next batch, it returns null and the loop breaks. If I comment the update statement, the loop times becomes to 20K+.